# Can't open SQL script in MySQL Event Scheduler body

Tags: mysql, events, syntax, mysql-error-1064, mysql-event

When I try open a script in the event scheduler with the source: `c:/path/path/file.sql` the following error occurs:

---

```
mysql> CREATE EVENT `TEST_load_import_script_user`
    -> ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-10-01 11:09:00'
    -> DO source c:/db/data_import/scripts/load_data_user.sql;
```

See Error:

```
*ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'c:/db/data_import/scripts/load_data_user.sql' at line 3*
```

---

BUT when I do a simple "Select * from" Command all works as expectet:

```
mysql> CREATE EVENT `TEST_load_import_script_user`
    -> ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-10-01 11:09:00'
    -> DO select * from user;
```

*Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)*

---

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? :)

---

**Additional Information that might help:**

- I am running `MySQL 8.0` on `Windows Server 2016` Yes the File does exist
- When I try to run the script outside of the Event Scheduler Syntax,
  no error is given and the script is being executed normally
- Event scheduler is ON

Comment: source is meant to use differently https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html..

Comment: 'Each stored program contains a body that consists of an SQL statement. This statement may be a compound statement made up of several statements separated by semicolon (;) characters.'  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html  (an event is a stored program).